# Option c and option s in pandas dataframe plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I saw the following snippet of code from a book I am studying from

```
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
 s=housing["population"]/100, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
 c="median_house_value", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), colorbar=True,
)
plt.legend()
```

`housing` here is a pandas dataframe. I checked the documentation for `pandas.DataFrame.plot`  on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html. However, I don't see anywhere on the link where it states what `c` and `s` mean. I can infer from the resulting figure what it means, but I'm wondering why does the documentation not show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should look at matplotlib documentation site, mentioned [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) . Since the default `plotting.backend` is set to matplotlib in pandas, so these things are mentioned there. Here is what it say:

> s: float or array-like, shape (n, ), optional
>
> ```
>     The marker size in points**2. Default is rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.
> ```
>
> c: array-like or list of colors or color, optional
>
> ```
> The marker colors. Possible values:
>
>     A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
>     A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.
>     A sequence of colors of length n.
>     A single color format string.
> ```